# Implementation of brush with x-axis zoom with nvd3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I need help in implementing dynamic x-axis with time range in nvd3.

I am using "line with finder chart" shown in the following examples. I have date plotted on my x-axis. When I reduce the finder window, I want to change the date format.
http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav

Following is the implementation with d3, The same behaviour I want to implement with finder. Here you can see when finder window changes, date format in main chart also changes. for smaller finder window date format becomes hourly.
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

Answer (score 0):

I could manage to get the solution from following stack overflow link. I added my answer there for latest nvd3 version.

[NVD3 time formatting , line with focus chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744202/nvd3-time-formatting-line-with-focus-chart/40713282#40713282)